# How to find out how many aircraft depart/land from a country per day?

Tags: air-traffic-control, airport, traffic-pattern, air-traffic-management, flight-tracking

I am trying to get the following information. I would like to know for each day how many aircraft have taken off and departed from a specific country. This information should be up to date and possibly have also some historical time series as well (for example the last month).
I know i could get such information by paying some services like Flight Aware or FlightRadar24 but I need to do it for free.
I tried OpenSky but the API doesn't offer much information (just time, lat/lon, origin).
Do you know a possible way to gather such information? It doesn't need to be machine readable as long it has the info.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The OpenSky API features [arrivals by airport](https://opensky-network.org/apidoc/rest.html#arrivals-by-airport) and [departures by airport](https://opensky-network.org/apidoc/rest.html#departures-by-airport) for a specified time window. Could you specify what else you need?

Comment: Lat/Lon (if that were all that was available) should be more than enough to localize to a country. Any GIS system would require than and something as simple as PowerBI or Tableau will plot the data on a map for you with just that info.

Comment: @FreeMan It's not even necessary to deal with coordinates: `estDepartureAirport` contains the "ICAO code of the estimated departure airport". The first two letters of the [ICAO code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Civil_Aviation_Organization#Airport_codes) tell you pretty much, which country you are in. Some countries have more than one prefix, but I'm sure, you'd find a list somewhere on the net.

Comment: @svoop I read, recognized, and understood your initial comment, therefore I added "(if that were all that was available)". Just providing another option for the OP.

Comment: You need to define what size/usage aircraft you’re interested in - scheduled airlines will be easier to find out than overnight cargo or general aviation.

Comment: @svoop Nothing more actually... I would like to know how many aircraft departed from china and arrived to china on a daily basis. Mostly interested in civil aviation